# locust request return error 502 when hitting my local flask web app

Tags: python, flask, locust

I am trying to create a locust test for load testting my flask app

This is my locustfile.py

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task


class DataBaseTest(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        pass

    @task(1)
    def get_home(self):
        self.client.get("/")


class WebsiteCassandra(HttpLocust):
    task_set = DataBaseTest
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

Running my flask web app in port 5000

```
app.run("0.0.0.0", 5000)
```

and in the directory where my locustfile.py lies

```
locust --host=http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

When I run the test I get the following failure

```
92  GET /   HTTPError(u'502 Server Error: Proxy Error ( Connection refused ) for url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/',)
```

Manually requesting the url works great. But not through locust. Why do you think it's that?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar problem, using the requests module, not locust.  I think the cause might be the same though.

For me, the problem was my proxy configuration.  I had the HTTP_PROXY environment variable set.  So requests picked up that setting and dutifully made the request through my proxy.
This means my script's connection went from my machine to the proxy, then back to my machine.  Because my machine's firewall doesn't have my development flask server's port open, the connection coming from the proxy was refused.

So, the short answer is to unset the http proxy in your script.  It's as easy as:

```
import os
del os.environ['http_proxy']
```